# If statement won't display?

Tags: php, select

I've got this code:

```
<?php
$filterUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
<select class="jsFilter" name="language">
    <option value>Sprache</option>
    <?php if (!$filterUrl == "www.domain.de"){?><option value="de" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Deutsch</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if (!$filterUrl == "www.domain.com"){?><option value="en" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='en'){echo "selected";}?>>English</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if (!$filterUrl == "www.domain.fr"){?><option value="fr" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='fr'){echo "selected";}?>>Français</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if (!$filterUrl == "www.domain.nl"){?><option value="nl" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='nl'){echo "selected";}?>>Nederlands</option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

I don't know why all the options aren't displayed?

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $filterUrl;`? check and tell

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $filterUrl;` above the select?

Comment: Try echoing `$filterUrl`

Comment: why this much if? one if condition will be fine.

Comment: I don't understand the entire setup. You're hiding and showing language options based on the domain, but then setting the default value based on the posted language. What determines the active language? The domain or `$_GET['language']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
$filterUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
<select class="jsFilter" name="language">
    <option value>Sprache</option>
    <?php if ($filterUrl != "www.domain.de"){?><option value="de" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Deutsch</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if ($filterUrl != "www.domain.com"){?><option value="en" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='en'){echo "selected";}?>>English</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if ($filterUrl != "www.domain.fr"){?><option value="fr" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='fr'){echo "selected";}?>>Français</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if ($filterUrl != "www.domain.nl"){?><option value="nl" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='nl'){echo "selected";}?>>Nederlands</option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: That works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $filterUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $language  = $_GET['language'];
?>
<select class="jsFilter" name="language">
    <option value>Sprache</option>
    <option value="de" <?php if(isset($language) && $language=='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Deutsch</option>
    <option value="en" <?php if(isset($language) && $language=='en'){echo "selected";}?>>English</option>
    <option value="fr" <?php if(isset($language) && $language=='fr'){echo "selected";}?>>Français</option>
    <option value="nl" <?php if(isset($language) && $language=='nl'){echo "selected";}?>>Nederlands</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could shorten this by putting `$_GET['language']` in it's own variable

Comment: Yes that's also possible.

Comment: I will try but theres some kind of syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you, perhaps, try it like this:

```
    <?php
        $filterUrl  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $options    = "";
        $language   = isset($_GET['language']) ? $_GET['language'] : "de";


        $options .= '<option value="de" ';
        if($language == "de"){$option .= "selected"; }
        $options .= '>Deutsch</option>';

        $options .= '<option value="en" ';
        if($language == "en"){$option .= "selected"; }
        $options .= '>English</option>';

        $options .= '<option value="fr" ';
        if($language == "fr"){$option .= "selected"; }
        $options .= '>Français</option>';

        $options .= '<option value="nl" ';
        if($language == "nl"){$option .= "selected"; }
        $options .= '>Nederlands</option>';

    ?>
```

Comment: No, still dont get any output of the options. The output of $filterUrl  is the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You have the conditions wrong, if you don't want to include the language option based on domain, it should be like this
`if ($filterUrl !== "www.domain.de")`. Your version `if (!$filterUrl == "www.domain.de")` first negates the string, which gives you empty string and then compares it which is obviously always false.

So the whole solution would look like this:

```
<?php
$filterUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
<select class="jsFilter" name="language">
    <option value>Sprache</option>
    <?php if ($filterUrl !== "www.domain.de"){?><option value="de" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Deutsch</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if ($filterUrl !== "www.domain.com"){?><option value="en" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='en'){echo "selected";}?>>English</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if ($filterUrl !== "www.domain.fr"){?><option value="fr" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='fr'){echo "selected";}?>>Français</option><?php } ?>
    <?php if ($filterUrl !== "www.domain.nl"){?><option value="nl" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='nl'){echo "selected";}?>>Nederlands</option><?php } ?>
</select>
```